# maven use release:branch to branch select modules

Tags: maven, branch, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven multi module project like so

```
modA  
modB
modC
modD
  custom-pom.xml
```

And here the pom

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xx.xx.correspondence</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxHudsonTP</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <modules>
  <module>modA</module>
  <module>modB</module>
 </modules>
</project>
```

Now, when I invoke release:branch with the intent of creating a branch on custom-pom.xml like so

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=new-branch -f custom-pom.xml
```

It ends up creating a branch with all 4 modules.

Is there any way using release plugin to make sure only selected modules are branched without resorting to branching each module separately.?

Any other maven plugins..?

**Edited**
The background of this questions stems from the fact that the svn repo that I am working with has about 20 different modules with 4 different artifacts that they need to generate.  I could have easily gone with grouping the modules into sub folders, but since a few modules are common between 
the artifacts, I didn't think too much into splitting them up.

I understand that branching all modules is trivial and probably simple to manage, but the other developers in the team have this feeling of dealing with too much for accomplishing simple tasks like a one line bug fix.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It is recommended to use `<profiles>` instead of `-f custom-pom.xml`, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for more details.

Comment: What is wrong with branching all the modules at once? Most Version Control systems make branching almost "free" in terms of storage and management. Also, Maven doesn't really play well when you try and "trick" it into doing things it doesn't like.

Comment: @yorkw - thats a good idea. +1 for that..

Comment: You mean that you have 20 (parent) projects with each 4 submodules ? ... indeed 80 artifacts ?

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy , No, there are 20 modules in a directory with 4 different artifacts resulting out them. There is no parent pom controlling the 20 modules, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AnandHemmige OK. Once again, the "good" pratice is to consider the 20 modules as "a whole", or at least as "some lifecycles joined projects". I will update my answer. What other projects are intended to ? Resources ? Tests ? Configuration ? Pre-processing ?

Comment: @AnandHemmige did you tried something ? What have you decided  ?

Comment: @Jean, been crazily busy over past few weeks... To answer your question  , the 20 modules basically represent about 4-5 different products.. to give an idea, `submodule1-api, submodule1-web, submodule1-ejb` together form one product ...For now, we are just branching all modules to make life easier. But at some point, we will just create different pom.xmls for each 'product' What is your opinion on this..?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no solution to answer what you asked.

You have to keep in mind that multimodule projects (aggregation) means that every submodule share the same application lifecycle. This is **really** what modules and aggregation are intended to.

I see 2 differents workarounds.

### You have 2 real differents lifecycles

There is indeed 2 groups in your 4 submodules, lets say group1 : A and B, group 2, C and D.

Split them into 2 new projects :

```
Group1
|-- Project A
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- Project B
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- pom.xml

Group2
|-- Project C
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- Project D
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- pom.xml
```

Pro : You may be able to branch group 1 and 2 separately.
Cons : You won't be able anymore to perform simultaneaous action (in one command) on every project (like realeasing or builind them)

### You really have 1 single lifecycle

This is probably the case. You may want to branch only 1 or 2 submodules because of your very good understanding of the underlying architecture of the project. An so, you don't want to deal with too many conf / artifacts / time building ... Indeed, all those reasons may have indirects impacts that you won't see. Always build the whole project !

If this is for space saving (however most of SCM allow you to branch with few space, like Yorkw said), because your SCM allow you to get only submodules (and maybe both, like for Clearcase) ... sorry, there is no solution. This is the maven way, and I think this is the good one. (ok it's a little bit demagogic, but I really believe what I said)

**Don't hesitate to explain us why you really want to branch only a subset of your modules.** If there is another reason, you may have more accurate(s) solution(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Judging by your answer, I really think my situation is closer to your first scenario - different lifecycles. However, I was hesitant to  group together into common folders since there are quite a few *shared* modules between 2 lifecycles. Hence, I could not figure out how a branch requiring some shared modules and some modules from other lifecycle would look like.  Any recommendations on that.. ?   I edited my original question explaining the background.

Comment: Project A and B are commmon dependencies, used by project C and D ? Like A = model, B = ejb/services, C = war and D = ear ? Like this ?